# How to change try/catch to double.TryParse

Tags: c#, double, tryparse

How can i change this code to double.TryParse? Without try/catch.

```
static double PromptForDouble(string promptMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine(promptMessage);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine(); // input = "12124124"
            return double.Parse(input); // 1.234
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Zła wartość");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it.

```cs
        var input = "122.3";
        if (double.TryParse(input, out var parsedInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"success {parsedInput}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"not able to parse {input}");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

```
            var success = double.TryParse("78787888", out var result);
            if (success)
                return result;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Zła wartość");
```

... and then return something that indicates the invalid input

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
static void Example() { 
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if(double.TryParse(input, out double d)) {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Double!");
    }
}
```